# AZ AKS nodepool aks-custom headers WindowsContainerRuntime=containerd is throwing error

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-cli, containerd

When I execute the following command for adding node pool in Azure CLI, getting the error "unrecognized arguments aks-custom-headers windowscontainerruntime=containerd"

az aks nodepool add --resource-group resource-group-name  --cluster-name [cluster] --os-type Windows --name nodepool --node-vm-size Standard_D4s_v3 --kubernetes-version 1.20.5 --aks-custom-headers WindowsContainerRuntime=containerd, --node-count 1

[image]

Comment: whats your `az cli` version, try updating to the latest one

Comment: Can you add this extension https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/draft and try running the command again? Refer here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/16017

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to run below CLI commands to add node pool in aks with custom header refer below:-***

My **az cli version:- 2.45.0**

```bash
az --version
```

[image]

***Installed aks-preview extension in my cli like below:-***

**Code:-**

```bash
az extension add --name aks-preview
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Created aks cluster with Admin username and password for aks custom header windows profile to work like below:-

**Code:-**

```bash
az aks create --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster --node-count 2 --enable-addons monitoring --generate-ssh-keys --windows-admin-username siliconuser --vm-set-type VirtualMachineScaleSets --network-plugin azure
```

Make sure you note down the Kubernetes version in my scenario its 1.24.9

**Output:-**
[image]

Now, I used the same version in adding aks node pool with custom header with windows profile and it got executed successfully like below:-

**Code:-**

```bash
az aks nodepool add --resource-group myResourceGroup --cluster-name myAKSCluster --os-type Windows --name npwcd --node-vm-size Standard_D4s_v3 --kubernetes-version 1.24.9 --aks-custom-headers WindowsContainerRuntime=containerd --node-count 1
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]

[image]

**Reference:-**

[az aks nodepool add - unrecognized arguments: --aks-custom-headers EnableUltraSSD=true · Issue #16017 · Azure/azure-cli · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/16017)

[azure-docs/quick-windows-container-deploy-cli.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/aks/learn/quick-windows-container-deploy-cli.md)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the az cli needs to be updated to the latest version. However, note that even if you don't specify the custom header, since this is above K8s 1.20, the Windows node pool will have containerd as the runtime.